# How do you stop vines from spreading?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Its annoying me because I built a room surrounding my city and the vines still came in.  The same thing happened to my friends city too. My friend covered a house in vines and it spread to our houses.

Answer (score 8):

Vines spread - it's what they do. To stop them spreading:

- remove the 'source' vines - the top ones, or ones on a block, and others hanging below will fall to the ground.
- use a moat, they won't spread over water

Comment: Is point one still true if every piece of vine is connected to a block?  (i.e. if the vine goes down a wall.)

Comment: It is not true unless the vines are "free hanging", where removing a vine near the top destroys all the vines hanging beneath it. Vines that have a surface to cling to will remain.

Comment: @JohntheGreen - fixed

Answer (score 7):

Looking at the [minecraft wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Vines) there are a couple of properties that might help you.

- Vines can be destroyed by fire or water.
- Vines occupy a block, so if a block is covered in a sign or ladder the vine can't grow there
- Vines will be destroyed when sand or gravel attempts to occupy the space adjacent to the vines
- Vines will disappear if a torch is placed on them.

You can remove the vines using a water source placed in a high area (I don't recommend using fire). And, as suggested by Rory Alsop build a moat to keep the vines out.

Comment: I placed torched next to mine but they still went on the ceiling and I got no clue on how to stop that.

Comment: @Spiral you could put a glass block on the ceiling, or another block that vines won't grow on directly

Answer (score 3):

(I'm assuming the question is not about how to eliminate vines, but how to constrain their growth to the desired location.)

Vines spread indefinitely downward into empty space. Vines spread sideways and upward as long as there are no more than four vines nearby. (I don't know exactly how far “nearby” is, but I know that vines on a wall will stop spreading once there are five vine-tops in the area. More research needed; the specific number is from Minecraft Wiki.) Therefore:

- To keep vines from spreading **downward**, you must occupy the space below them. A popular block to do this with is [string](https://minecraft.wiki/w/String) (a.k.a. tripwire), because it is nearly invisible and can be placed in midair.
- To keep vines from spreading **sideways or upward**, you must either occupy the space such as with string or torches, or make sure that there are at least five vines closely grouped where you want them and not where you don't.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is use string, if you want vines to not grow. Since string is stackable and nearly invisible, you could use that to keep the vines from spreading. You can also use ladders and trapdoors -- basically anything that is not a whole block, except glass.

Answer (score 0):

Vines don't "jump" from one building to another, and don't spread across flat ground. This may have been different in early snapshots, but in the current version, vines can only spread out across a wall, or grow downwards into open air. If it does the latter, it stops growing once it reaches the ground.

So long as you keep a gap of more than one block between your buildings, the vines will only stay on one of them.